# Property Relation on Gibbs free energy

Tags: thermodynamics, entropy, physical-chemistry

My teacher told me that gibbs free energy is mathematically defined as G=H-TS.
(H:enthalpy, T:temperature, S:entropy)

When taking the differential and solving the 1st Law and 2nd Law together,
We get **dG=VdP-SdT**;

Note that (i)we have considered only PV work.
(ii)We have taken the Clausius Inequality as:-
dS=dq/T which is true for reversible processes only.

On the other hand, we know that for reversible process, ΔG=0 as ΔS(universe)=0.

consequently, dG=0. So can we say that VdP=TdS always?

My question is :- when can we apply the relation dG=VdP-SdT..... like can we apply it for *a chemical reaction that is occuring?*(I hope we cannot... as it is spontaneous and we can only apply it for reversible process, which are IMPOSSIBLE to occur) or for a *phase transition*(which should occur at constant T and P right? meaning that dG=0 for it and it will never occur)?

I am just so much confused.

Comment: "*On the other hand, we know that for reversible process, ΔG=0 as ΔS(universe)=0.*" Please explain how you obtain the former from the latter. From $dG=V\,dP-S\,dT$, I can increase $G$ for a system if I increase the pressure (even reversibly), for example. Furthermore, I don't see where you're using the Clausius equality. The equation $dG=V\,dP-S\,dT$ holds even in the case of irreversibility.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: @Chemomechanics how can you say that dG=VdP-SdT is valid for irreversible processes? Don't you know that TdS=dq is only possible in the case of reversible process?!.. this is what we used to derive that dG=VdP-TdS!!

Comment: The ultimate equation contains [only state variables](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_thermodynamic_relation#The_first_and_second_laws_of_thermodynamics), which don’t vary depending on whether entropy increases elsewhere in the universe. The equation always applies.

Comment: @Chemomechanics yes, i did see the wikipedia article, thank you! I'm very new to this and i will try my best to understand whatever is written, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First I need to correct one of your statements:

- For general reversible process it is **not** true that $dG=0$. For $dG$ to be zero the process must be reversible **and** $T$ and $P$ must be constant. Phase transitions are such a case. In general, however, $P$ and $T$ are not constant. For example, in reversible adiabatic process the condition that fixes the path is $dS=0$. The Gibbs energy along this path is $\Delta G = \Delta(H-TS) = \Delta H - S\Delta T$ and is not generally zero (you can use an ideal gas to demonstrate this).

Can we $dG = P dV - S dT$ to a spontaneous, and thus irrevesible reaction?

Yes, under a special condition: Suppose we have an irreversible process from equilibrium state $A$ to equilibrium state $B$. We may construct a *reversible* path between the end states and apply $dG = P dV - S dT$ along that path to calculate $\Delta G_{AB}$. This procedure will give the correct answer for $\Delta G_{AB}$ regardless of the reversible path we use in the calculation.

What we *cannot* do is apply $dG = P dV - S dT$ along the *actual* path from $A$ to $B$. This is because the actual path is generally a sequence of non equilibrium states on which thermodynamics does not apply.

Comment: You mean for an irreversible and thus spontaneous process, we can apply dG=PdV-SdT but only when we construct a completely different mechanism consisting of equilibrium states (whose state variables(P,V,T,H,U,G) are defined at each instant of the process) on which the laws of thermodynamics apply and calculate integral of dG i.e. ΔG for the process. But unfortunately, for equilibrium processes, ΔG=0 and thus I stand right. Please point out where i am wrong.... By the way, your answer was very good.

Comment: @robustrimo  The difference $\Delta G_{12}$ between two states depends only on the *end* states, not on how they are connected. A real process goes from 1 to 2 via a complicated irreversible path; we go via a nice path of equilibrium states and use to calculate $\Delta G_{12}$ by integrating $dG = V dP-S dT$. The result is the same $\Delta G_{12}$ as for the actual process. Your error is to say that "for reversible process $\Delta G=0$".  I will give a numerical example in my next comment below.

Comment: *Reversible adiabatic expansion of steam* from $T_1=400$C, $P_1=20$ bar, $H_1=3248.2$ kJ/kg, $S_1=7.1290$ kJ/kg K; to $T_2=301.207$C, $P_2=10$ bar, $H_2=3054.27$ kJ/kg, $S_2=7.129$ kJ/kg K: for this process $G_1 = 3248.2 - (400 + 273.15) (7.1290) = -1550.69$ kJ/kg, $G_2=3054.27 - (301.207 + 273.15) (7.1290) = -1040.32$, therefore $\Delta G_{12}=510.37$ kJ/kg.

Answer (score 1):

The equation dG=-SdT+VdP applies to the differential change in G between two closely neighboring thermodynamic equilibrium states, one at (T,P) and the other at (T+dT,P+dP) of a single phase constant composition system.  It does not matter about any process path or reversibility/irreversibility.  This is strictly a physical property relationship.

Comment: Doesn't reversible actually mean equilibrium? Which means that dG=0 for equilibrium process?

Comment: @robustrimo Only if it is for a single phase not undergoing a chemical reaction.